# Remove items less than 10 from the stack

Tags: c, struct

Numbers are pushed onto the stack, you need to pop the full stack, after which, the stack in which elements less than 10 are removed. Example code when all elements of the stack are removed:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>
struct kkk 
{
    float elem[15]; 
    int top; // index of the top rlrment
};
struct kkk* st, * element; // pointers

void Init(struct kkk* st) // initialization
{
    st->top = NULL; 
}

void Push(struct kkk* st, float f) // push an item onto the stack
{
    if (st->top < 15)
    {
        st->elem[st->top] = f;
        st->top++;
    }
    else
        printf("Stack full\n");

}

float Pop(struct kkk* st) // pop an item from the stack
{
    float el;
    if ((st->top) > 0)
    {
        st->top--;
        el = st->elem[st->top];
        return el;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Stack is empty \n");
        return 0;
    }
}

float Vulychtop(struct kkk* st) // deleting the top of the stack
{
    if ((st->top) > 0) {
        return(st->elem[st->top - 1]);
    }
    else {
        printf("Stack is empty!\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int Gettop(struct kkk* st) // top element of the stack without delting
{
    return(st->top);
}

int Isempty(struct kkk* st) // check 
{
    if ((st->top) == 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void Vuvid(struct kkk* st) // Output of all elements
{
    int i;
    i = st->top;
    if (Isempty(st) == 1) return;
    do {
        i--;
        printf("%f\n", st->elem[i]);
    } while (i > 0);
}
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int i, n, k;
    float znach;
    element = (struct kkk*)malloc(sizeof(struct kkk));
    Init(element);
    printf("Enter the number of items in the stack \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the number %d: ", i);
        scanf("%f", &znach);
        Push(element, znach);
    }
    printf("In stack %d elements \n", Gettop(element));
    printf("\n");
    Vuvid(element);
    printf("Top element %f\n", Vulychtop(element));
    do {
        printf("The element to be removed %f, ", Pop(element));
        printf("Items left in the stack %d \n", Gettop(element));
    } while (Isempty(element) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLczr.png

I create a stack, after which I start entering numbers into it. With that, I'm fine. Next, I find the top element of the stack and pop it out. After that, I need **to remove those numbers from the stack, the value of which is less than 10**, and I manage to completely clear the stack one by one. Can't make a condition for this.

Comment: Possibly replace the russian text with english text. And show an example of input and expected vs actual output

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The condition for testing if a number `n` is less than 10 is `n < 10`.

Comment: @Anton Tretiak Do you need to remove all elements of the stack that are less than 10? If so then you need for example an auxiliary stack if to use the stack interface for the operation without directly accessing the array elem.

Comment: Are you required to only use the stack interface (only push and pop) or may you directly access the underlying array? The latter way would be simpler...

Comment: @SergeBallesta No, it is not required, I tried this method yesterday and it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text but post text as properly formatted text. You can copy text from the console and paste it into the question.

Comment: @SergeBallesta hmmm... why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @4386427: Because OP's comment made me think that it did not help them. Feel free to reuse its content if you want to...

Comment: Presumably, a recursive solution is possible.  Pop till pop fails, then check and push if => 10.  Would that not be actually easier than creating another container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use another stack as temporary storage. In pseudo-code something like:

```
* create tmp-stack
* while org-stack isn't empty
    * data = pop org-stack
    * if (data >= 10) push data to tmp-stack
* while tmp_stack isn't empty
    * data = pop tmp_stack
    * push data to org-stack
* free tmp-stack
```

This can be implemented using the already existing function.

Better performance can be achieved by operating directly on the array holding the stacks data. Based on ideas from @SergeBallesta it may look like:

```
* write-index = 0;
* read-index = 0;
* while read-index < top
    * if array[read-index] >= 10
        * array[write-index] = array[read-index]
        * write-index = write-index + 1
    * read-index = read-index + 1
* top = write-index
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using an old MS compiler. For example the header `<malloc.h>` is not a standard C header. Instead you should use the header `<stdlib.h>`. Also neither declaration from the header `<math.h>` is used. So you may remove the inclusion of the header.

The function `Gettop` does not do what is written in the comment for the function

```
// top element of the stack without delting
```

Actually it returns the current value of the data member `st->top` that is how many elements are present in the stack.

On the other hand, the comment for the function `Vulychtop`

```
// deleting the top of the stack
```

is incorrect. The function does not delete an element from the stack because the value of the data member `st->top` is not decreased. Also such a function should not output any message. It is the function `Pop` that removes an element from the stack.

The function `Vulychtop` could be defined the following way

```
int Vulychtop( struct kkk *st, float *value ) 
{
    if ( st->top != 0 ) *value = st->elem[st->top - 1];
    
    return st->top != 0; 
}
```

The function `Pop` also should not issue any message and return an element of the stack.

Also there is no great sense to declare the pointer `element` in the file scope. It could be declared in `main`.

The pointer `st` declared in the file scope

```
struct kkk* st, * element; // pointers
            ^^
```

is not used in the program.

Also there is no need to allocate an object of the type `struct kkk` dynamically.
You could just write in `main`

```
struct kkk element;
Init( &element );
```

To remove elements that are less than 10 from the original stack using the open interface of the stack you need an auxiliary stack.

For example

```
struct kkk st;
Init( &st );

while( !Isempty( element ) )
{
    float value;
    Vulychtop( element, &value ); // here I am using the function definition I showed above

    if ( !( value < 10.0f ) ) Push( &st, value );
    Pop( element );
} 


while( !Isempty( &st ) )
{
    float value;
    Vulychtop( &st, &value ); // here I am using the function definition I showed above

    Push( element, value );
    Pop( &st );
}
```

You can yourself add messages in the while loops about what elements are popped, pushed or removed.

Pay attention that as you allocated an object of the type `struct kkk` dynamically you should free it before exiting the program

```
free( element );
```